# Есть ссылка, и надо открыть jquery(ajax) блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

С новым годом всех!
Есть ссылка `<a href='id?<php script>'>Статистика</a>` она у меня находиться в меню юзера, но если просто добавить `#tabs-2` к той ссылке- ничего не произойдет(тоесть `<a href='id?<php script>#tabs-2'>Статистика</a>`, так как скрипт на Jquery(ajax) как я понял,вопрос в том, как открыть через ссылку?

```js
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  var pluginName = "tabulous",
    defaults = {
      effect: 'scale'
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.$elem = $(this.element);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {

    init: function() {

      var links = this.$elem.find('a.tabsxsw');
      var firstchild = this.$elem.find('li:first-child').find('a.tabsxsw');
      var lastchild = this.$elem.find('li:last-child').after('<span class="tabulousclear"></span>');

      if (this.options.effect == 'scale') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescale');
      } else if (this.options.effect == 'slideLeft') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideleft');
      } else if (this.options.effect == 'scaleUp') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescaleup');
      } else if (this.options.effect == 'flip') {
        tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideflip');
      }

      var firstdiv = this.$elem.find('#tabs_container');
      var firstdivheight = firstdiv.find('div:first').height();

      var alldivs = this.$elem.find('div:first').find('div');

      alldivs.css({
        'top': '0px'
      });

      firstdiv.css('height', firstdivheight + 'px');

      firstchild.addClass('tabulous_active');

      links.bind('click', {
        myOptions: this.options
      }, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $options = e.data.myOptions;
        var effect = $options.effect;

        var mythis = $(this);
        var thisform = mythis.parent().parent().parent();
        var thislink = mythis.attr('href');


        firstdiv.addClass('transition');

        links.removeClass('tabulous_active');
        mythis.addClass('tabulous_active');
        thisdivwidth = thisform.find('div' + thislink).height();

        if (effect == 'scale') {
          alldivs.removeClass('showscale').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hidescale');
          thisform.find('div' + thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showscale');
        } else if (effect == 'slideLeft') {
          alldivs.removeClass('showleft').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hideleft');
          thisform.find('div' + thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showleft');
        } else if (effect == 'scaleUp') {
          alldivs.removeClass('showscaleup').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hidescaleup');
          thisform.find('div' + thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showscaleup');
        } else if (effect == 'flip') {
          alldivs.removeClass('showflip').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hideflip');
          thisform.find('div' + thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showflip');
        }

        firstdiv.css('height', thisdivwidth + 'px');
      });

    },

    yourOtherFunction: function(el, options) {
      // some logic
    }
  };

  // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
  // preventing against multiple instantiations
  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new Plugin(this, options);
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#tabsx').tabulous({
    effect: 'slideLeft'
  });
});
```

```css
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: expression(hideFocus='true');
}

#tabs_container {
  padding: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

#tabs_container div {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.transition {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
  -o-transition-delay: .3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: .3s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.make_transist {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.hidescale {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.showscale {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
  -o-transition-delay: .3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: .3s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.hideleft {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.showleft {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  -o-transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
  -o-transition-delay: .3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: .3s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.hidescaleup {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.showscaleup {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
  -o-transition-delay: .3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: .3s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.hideflip {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-90deg) scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-90deg) scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: rotatey(-90deg) scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: rotatey(-90deg) scale(1.1);
  transform: rotatey(-90deg) scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.showflip {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
  -o-transition-delay: .3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: .3s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(0deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(0deg) scale(1);
  -o-transform: rotatey(0deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: rotatey(0deg) scale(1);
  transform: rotatey(0deg) scale(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.tabsxsw_active {
  background: white !important;
  color: #655c89 !important;
}

.tabsxswclear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabsx">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="tabsxsw" href="#tabs-1" title="">Информация</a></li>
    <li><a class="tabsxsw" href="#tabs-2" title="">Статистика</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs_container">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      ..................................................................................................................
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      ...........................................s................................................
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не могу понять вашу проблему, ведь приведенный код работает...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать блок, в него поместить вкладки и его содержимое, а далее указать на этот блок.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Первая вкладка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Вторая вкладка</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Текст с первой вкладки</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Текст со второй вкладки</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: То что вы предложили- не сработало.

Comment: Проверьте правку

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, попробуйте поставить перед этим ссылку `<a href="#tabs-2">тест</a>`- она не заработает...

Comment: Так надо ссылки использовать в пределах `<div id="tabs">`
На крайний случай, обозначать эти ссылки как-то, например:
`<a href="#tabs-2" id="tabs-2">тест</a>
<script>$("#tabs-2").tabs();</script>`
Желательно подгружать после загрузки всего контента содержимое <script>, как в основном комментарии

Comment: Суть в том что эта ссылка находиться далеко за пределами `<div id="tabs">`, а точнее в верхнем блоке, и мне надо чтобы при переходе открывалась 2 вкладка- "Статистика"